# Fonts not working in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

All my fonts work perfectly in Photoshop, but when I open Illustrator and try to use them, lots of them are not working. If I select the first font in Illustrator, and press the down arrow to scroll down through the fonts, when it reaches a font that is not working, all the scrolling jumps to the bottom of the font list (to the fonts starting with M, or Z).

Why are the fonts working in Photoshop, and in Illustrator they don't?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this once before, it can happen when you have a font file in your system that is somehow corrupted. Once Illustrator tries to load it (triggered by your scrolling). Photoshop is apparently more tolerant. The solution is unfortunately not convenient; you need to identify which font file is causing Illustrator to freak out and uninstall it from your system.

As a preventative measure, I always load fonts used for design in Illustrator's font directory (that's `Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CC 2015\Fonts` on Windows, see [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/11394/8708) for alternatives) instead of installing it on the system. That way if I do add a font that provokes this behavior, it's easier to identify and remove.